# Looking for an example using AudioRecord

Tags: android, audio-recording

Am trying to write an app that reads from the microphone and where I, in the same app, write the results/buffer myself to my own file (in a separate thread).  Believe me I have Googled till my fingers were numb.  But I am having a problem with the whole "callback" part.

Whether it's the onPeriodicNotification or onMarkerReached part, I just can't seem to get it right.  Not looking for anyone to write it for me, but if I could just find the proper shell online, I could do it myself.

So if anyone knows of a good example, please.

Answer (score -1):

Made a simple Sound Manager in which you can record sound :

```
public class SoundManager {

private static final String TAG = SoundManager.class.getSimpleName();
public boolean isRecording = false;
private MediaRecorder recorder;
private String audioFileName = "sound";

private Context mContext;
private String storePath;

public SoundManager(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
}

public void onRecord(boolean toStart) {
    if (toStart) {
        try {
            startRecording();
            isRecording = true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("Tag", e.toString());
        }
    } else {
        stopRecording();
    }
}

private void startRecording() throws IOException {
    stopRecording();
    audioFileName = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    storePath = new File(mContext.getExternalFilesDir(null), "/images/"+ audioFileName+".3gp").getAbsolutePath();
    recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
    recorder.setOutputFile(storePath);

    recorder.prepare();
    recorder.start();
}

private void stopRecording() {
    if (isRecording && recorder != null) {
        try {
            recorder.stop();
            recorder.release();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            recorder.release();
            Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
        }

        recorder = null;
        isRecording = false;
    }
}

public File getAudioOutputPath() {
    return new File(storePath);
}
```

}

**Uses:**

1. Start Record : `soundManager.onRecord(true);`
2. Stop Record  : `soundManager.onRecord(false);`
3. get sound file path : `soundManager.getAudioOutputPath();`

Add audio permission in your Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

`

Comment: I appreciate it, but what I want to be able to do is grab from the buffer the audio and write it to a file myself, hence trying to learn AudioRecord which has the callback routines for that.

I just can't figure them out, so was looking for an example of the code online which I would then learn from and build from there.

Comment: sorry to hear that. Can you tell me why you need the buffer while recording? If you need to view something then i have a way to do that.

Comment: Just looking to be able to do the writing myself.  Whether it's breaking it up realtime or analyzing in realtime. All that I google pointed to the AudioRecord class.  Just at the beginning of learning it so was looking for an online example.

Comment: Is there anyone who can help me with this?  Please?

Comment: check this community.. you will find lots of people specially who works in google https://plus.google.com/u/1/communities/105153134372062985968